# Testing simple component that uses React Query

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-query

How would I write a passing test for the following? Where getLifestages is a working get API call that returns an array such as:

`[{_id: 1, title: 'School'},{_id: 2, title: 'Work'}]`

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';

const useLifestages = () => useQuery(
    ['GET_LIFESTAGES'],
    getLifestages,
    {
        staleTime: params.staleTime,
        keepPreviousData: true
    }
);

const LandingScreen = () => {
  const { data: lifestages, isLoading } = useLifestages();

  if (isLoading) return <Loading />

  return (
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <div className="container">
        <header className="header">
          Heading
        </header>
        <input 
          className="search-bar" 
          type='search' 
          role='search' 
        />
        
        {lifestages.map(lifestage => (
          <div
            key={lifestage._id}
            lifestage={lifestage} 
            role='button'
          />
        ))}

      </div>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};
```

I want to mock the API response and what I've done so far hasn't worked.

```
jest.mock('react-query', () => ({
  useQuery: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(({ 
     data: [{
         _id: 1, title: 'School'
       },{
         _id: 2, title: 'Work'
     }], 
     isLoading: false
}));

describe("Load landing screen", () => {
  
    it("Renders the buttons", () => {
       render(
         <LandingScreen />
       );
       const button = screen.getByRole('button');
       expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
    })

});
```

The error I'm seeing is this:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(0 , _queries.useLifestages)(...)' as it is undefined.

       8 |
       9 |
    > 10 |   const { data: lifestages, isLoading } = useLifestages();
```

It seems to me that perhaps it's because the data hasn't returned from the call yet and is giving undefined. But clearly my mock isn't working as it shouldn't be calling the API at all ideally and instead using my mocked data. I'm a little confused as I'm new to testing async code so any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
jest.mock('react-query', () => ({
  useQuery: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(({ 
     data: [{
         _id: 1, title: 'School'
       },{
         _id: 2, title: 'Work'
     }], 
     isLoading: false
}));
```

This mocks the whole react-query library and just gives it a `useQuery` hook. I'm thinking that this won't work because other vital parts are then missing. It's like mocking `React` and only giving it a `useEffect` hook ...

I think you would be much better off not mocking 3rd party libraries, but mocking what you have control over, which is either how the QueryFunction is implemented, or, by just mocking the network layer.

Mocking the network layer is what is recommended [in the docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/testing#testing-network-calls) (e.g. with nock) and [in my blog](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/testing-react-query#mocking-network-requests) (e.g. with msw)

Advantages of mocking the network layer is that you'll not only test if your component will work if `useQuery` returns `data`, but also, what happens if it returns a `loading` state. By mocking `useQuery`, this implementation would pass the test:

```
function LandingScreen() {
  const data = useQuery(...)
  
  return query.data.map(...)
}
```

but it would certainly die at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar error a while back, what I did was instead of using a mock I spied on the ReactQuery; like this:

```
jest
      .spyOn(ReactQuery, 'useQuery')
      .mockImplementation(
        jest
          .fn()
          .mockReturnValue({ data: { ...SomeMockData }, isLoading: false, isSuccess: true, isError: false })
      )
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What is the variable ReactQuery - I have assumed it is an import of the library e.g. import * as ReactQuery from 'react-query'? With this I'm still getting the same error, so just wanted to double check

Comment: Yes, but maybe you need to look at the mock; try to spyOn the API call and let that one return a promise resolve. So something like `jest.spyOn(API, "getLifestages").mockResolvedValueOnce(someMock);`